# undefined variable in hidden text while trying out e-commerce website

Tags: php

I'm following a tutorial on youtube about e-commerce website..

I'm doing an admin page of editing a product.
However, I met with an  Undefined variable: targetID  at this line.
But I thought that I've already define it/

```
  <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
```

Can someone help me?

this is my code...

the php code for inventoryedit.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['description'])){

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $product_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
    $product_description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $product_package = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_package']);


$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE supermarket SET name='$product_name', price='$product_price' packaging='$product_package' , category='$category', subcategory='$category' , description='$product_description' WHERE id='$pid'");


if($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    //place image in the folder
$newname = "$product_description.jpg";
//place image in the folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
    header("location: inventoryedit.php"); 
    exit();

}

}

?>

<?php 
//gather this product full info
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$targetID' LIMIT 1");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count output amount
if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $product_description = $row["description"];
        $product_name = $row["name"];
        $category = $row["category"];
        $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
        $product_price = $row["price"];
        $product_package = $row["packaging"];




    }
}
else{
    $product_list = "Sorry, it don't exist";
    exit();
}
}

?>
```

the html code for inventoryedit.php

```
 <form action="inventoryedit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" method="post">
   <table width="600" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">

 <tr>
 <td width="175">Category:</td>
 <td width="405">
 <label>
 <select name="category" id="category">
 <option value="<?php echo $category ?>"><?php echo $category ?></option>
 <option value="SnacksAndTibits">SnacksAndTibits</option>
 <option value="Beverages">Beverages</option>
 <option value="Toiletries">Toiletries</option>
 </select>
 </label>



  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Subcategory:</td>
 <td>
  <label>
 <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
 <option value="<?php echo $subcategory ?>"><?php echo $subcategory ?></option>
 <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
 <option value="Lozenges">Lozenges</option>
 <option value="PotatoSnacks">Potato Snacks</option>
 <option value="Carbonated">Carbonated</option>
 <option value="Juice">Juice</option>
 <option value="EnergyDrink">Energy Drink</option>
 <option value="FacialCare">Facial Care</option>
 <option value="BodyWashSoap">Body Wash/Soap</option>
 <option value="Toothbursh">Toothbursh</option>

 </select>
 </label>


  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Product Name:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" size="64" value="<?php echo $product_name ?>" required="require" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td height="101">Product Description:</td>
 <td><textarea name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo $product_description ?>" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Product Package:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="product_package" id="product_package" value="<?php echo $product_package ?>" size="64" required="require" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Product Price:</td>
 <td>$
   <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" size="12" value="<?php echo $product_price ?>"required="require" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Product Image:</td>
 <td><label>   <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField">
 </label>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>
          <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update Items"></td>
 </tr>

 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated and very dangerous if one is not careful with escaping. Use PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You call:

```
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
...
```

But there is no else case, and `$targetID` is not defined anywhere else.
So any time you don't have a `pid` in your URL you will get this error.

Comment: what can I do to improve on>

Comment: this is when i click edit, then it will have PID, thus it will update the database

Comment: It looks like you should be using `$pid` instead of `$targedID`